# pixijs add event to stage from inside a sprite

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm trying to clean my code (coming from OO languages) so I've created a class Card that extends Sprite.
Dragging the Card around should work like in the examples: https://pixijs.io/examples/#/events/dragging.js
Here you have to add an event listener to the stage in order to react to mouse movement outside your sprite.
If I want to do the same inside the Sprite (or Card), I thought I could add the event listener to the parent, since the sprite has been added to the stage, but apparently it doesn't work.

```js
app.stage.addEventListener('pointermove', onDragMove);
```

becomes

```js
selectedTarget.parent.addEventListener('pointermove', onDragMove);
```

I even tried to pass the app :

```js
export class Card extends PIXI.Sprite {
  constructor(app,x, y, sw, sh, texture) {
    this.app = app;
```

(side note: I also don't know how to get the app.screen.width, so I passed it as sw before passing the whole app)

I then have the function onDragMove(e) outside the class (It does make sense) and in there I use the other variable defined outside (selectedTarget) a bit like dragTarget on pixijs' example.

All the changes doesn't give any error, but I can cleary see that once my mouse pointer is outside the sprite, the event is not emitted, which means that the sprite's parent isn't really the stage or it's not the same stage. The same happens if i get the app with selectedTaget.app.stage.addEventListerner...

I think my question is more Javascript related than pixi.js

Comment: "addEventListener" is for DOM-Elements. Pixi renders everything into a canvas, which receives those events. From there you'll have to handle the games behavior yourself (check where drag starts, if mouse is overlapping sprite, start moving, etc). You can't use "addEventListener" on Pixi-sprites.

Comment: @niorad the example provided use on() instead of addEventListener, but the result is exactly the same.

Comment: @niorad actually in new PixiJS v7 they introduced https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/wiki/v7-Migration-Guide#-replaces-interactionmanager-with-eventsystem - `We added addEventListener and removeEventListener APIs to DisplayObject which have the same DOM signature and can be used instead of on and off.`

Comment: please check "Events" examples at https://pixijs.io/examples/#/events/